# jquery while loop not working with some values

Tags: jquery

so i have the following jquery code , the while loop works(i.e the loop runs and the $total changes) perfectly with some value and not at all with others :

```
function yearshad ($a, $b) {
var $somenewval=$a;
var $total = 0.0;
console.log($a);// console debug
console.log($b); // console debug
while ($a>$b) {
    console.log($a); // console debug
    $a -= 1.0;
    $total += 1.0/$a;
    console.log($a); // console debug
    console.log($b); // console debug
}
var $result2 = $total * $somenewval;
return $result2;
}
```

without the debug console.log commands:

```
function yearshad ($a, $b) {
var $somenewval=$a;
var $total = 0.0;
while ($a>$b) {
    $a -= 1.0;
    $total += 1.0/$a;   
}
var $result2 = $total * $somenewval;
return $result2;
```

}

some working values............. $a=22  $b=2   ,  $a=6  $b=4   ,  $a=5  $b=3 , $a=22  $b=11

some values that dont work  $a=22  $b=3  ,  $a=22  $b=10  ,  $a=34  $b=7

Does anyone have ANY clue what could be causing this??

thanks in advance

the function is called from:

```
function mainfunction() {
$a = $('#currentage').val();
$b = $('#memorystart').val();
$result = yearshad ($a, $b);
$answer = 'random text' + $result + 'random text';
    $('#resultline').html($answer);
}
```

Comment: show from where you calling it

Comment: What does "works" mean?

Comment: Why in the world do you put `$` in front of every variable name?  It does not help the readability of your code in any way.

Comment: What output you want ?

Comment: so i added where its called from....

works i.e it runs and the $total changes .....

the $ thing, just being a noob, though it would help me know when i was dealing with jquery variables....

output: some value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not converting the strings from the input fields to numbers before attempting to do comparison operations on them.  In your function, passing the string `"22"` generates a different result than passing the number `22`.

If you add this to the start of your function:

```
$a = +$a;
$b = +$b;
```

Then, it will convert both arguments to numbers.

```
function yearshad($a, $b) {
    $a = +$a;
    $b = +$b;
    var $somenewval = $a;
    var $total = 0.0;
    while ($a > $b) {
        $a -= 1.0;
        $total += (1.0 / $a);
        console.log($total); // console debug
    }
    var $result2 = $total * $somenewval;
    return $result2;
}
```

FYI, it is likely the comparison that was failing on strings because `"22" < "3"` which isn't the case if they are numbers.

Comment: hmm ok :)  , so would that explain why some value work just fine?

Comment: @user3718034 , use parseInt()

Comment: this worked perfectly thanks A LOT, been struggling with this for several hours.(nooblife)  :D

Comment: @beepbaapboom - Since it looks like you may be new to StackOverflow, you may want to know that when you get an answer that solves your problem, the general procedure here is that you mark the best answer as your selected answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  That rewards the person who provided the answer and provides both you and the answerer with some reputation points which can earn you additional privileges here on StackOverflow.